# Why is the wave texture not texturing these spheres?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, procedural

In this setup the plane, the cube, the uv and ico spheres, all these are assigned the same material.

[image]

Comment: Did you assign the material to the spheres?  Please show an image of the material you have for them (not for the plane)

Comment: @cegaton please see first sentence (and the pictured setup).

Comment: I will learn how to read eventually...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *Rings* mode of the **Wave Texture** node radiates from the object center in concentric shells. Because of that, the surfaces of your spheres are passing through a single shell, and therefore a single color. If you look at the edges of your images, where the distance from the center is a bit further, you can see that they are darkened:

[image]

To fix this, you can offset the location (or scale) with your mapping node:

[image]

Alternatively, if you wanted to make all the rings radiate from the same point, you could select an object in the bottom slot of the **Texture Coordinate** node (I chose the plane):

[image]

As a side note, the Icosphere looks pretty cool if it's scaled a bit differently:

[image]

Comment: Now I can sleep

Comment: Cancelled last comment. Just looked at your edited answer. Now I can't sleep. Gotta try that plane coordinate. Fascinating.